# File system implementation in MongoDB with GridFS

Tags: file-systems, mongo

I am working on two projects that will both implement a [Webdav](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918) server backed by a [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) GridFS. In each case, there is the potential for the system to store tens of millions of files spread across thousands of hierarchical directories.

I can come up with two different ways of storing the directory structure:

- As a "true" hierarchical file system, with directories containing the IDs (`_id`) of subdirectories and regular files. The paths will be separated by slashes (`/`) as in a POSIX-compliant file system.
- The path `/a/b/c` will be represented as a directory `a` containing a directory `b` containing a file `c`.
- As a flat file system, where file names include the slashes.
- The path `/a/b/c` will be stored as a single file with the name `/a/b/c`

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each, with respect to a "real" folder-based file system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Trees+in+MongoDB ? It looks like you're between "Child Links" and "Materialized Paths". Based on the commentary it seems that your second idea is a much better fit for Mongo. Storing each subdirectory `_id` is a little too relational and implies linking and joins which are not things that Mongo excels at.